# Update table_name set column1 from where column2 (column2 mutiple diffirent value)?

Tags: mysql, java

Hi I'm working with this Query to update all the row in the table using a String of multiple values.
I'm trying some Query but i get an error

the error is "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"

this is my query

```
String text = textarea.getText();

      String sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `status`= 'YES' WHERE no_id ='"+text+"'";
      pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.execute();
```

my string is from a textarea listed all different value i need

Comment: I'm sorry that is for Executing a query I already update

Comment: And nevertheless... What is final `sql` value? show...

Comment: you mean the ouput of the query?

Comment: Print out your SQL string and post it here!

Comment: sorry what do mean SQL string i should post?

Comment: The value of `sql` variable after assigning operator.

Comment: if you prepare a statement. use the `text` as the argument to execute, and the placeholder that you put in your query string.

Comment: what is the value of text? if id is an integer field it must be also Integer, so why is mysql thiniking that you are using a double.?

Comment: Show us a sample "sql" after "text" is built into it.